# Can struts logic tag evaluate a variable's contents?

Tags: jsp, struts, tags

Below is what I'm trying to achieve. The problem is "errors" is not defined. If I remove my match logic, the errors are displayed on the web page. Is there anyway of evaluating the text the error contains?

```
<logic:messagesPresent>
    <tr>
        <td class="errorcicon"><img src="images/icon_caution.gif" width="18" height="18" alt="Caution" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="4"><html:errors /></td>
    </tr>
</logic:messagesPresent>


<logic:match name="errors" property="text" value="Service Start date is required" >
    <% pageContext.setAttribute("NOORIGIONALSERVICEDATE", "-1");%>
</logic:match>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the question you ask fits the problem. Take a look at the taglib documentation for [`<logic:messagesPresent>`](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.8/struts-taglib/tlddoc/logic/messagesPresent.html)

I believe what you need is `<logic:messagesPresent message="false">` which should look at the `Globals.ERROR_KEY` instead of the `Globals.MESSAGE_KEY`. The message attribute is "true" by default.

Comment: How about some voting love for that answer?

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your bug:

```
<logic:messagesPresent>
    <tr>
        <td class="errorcicon"><img src="images/icon_caution.gif" width="18" height="18" alt="Caution" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="4"><html:errors /></td>
    </tr>
</logic:messagesPresent>

<logic:present name="errors">
    <logic:match name="errors" property="text" value="Service Start date is required" >
        <% pageContext.setAttribute("NOORIGIONALSERVICEDATE", "-1");%>
    </logic:match>
</logic:present>
```

logic:present allows you to test if a bean is in present in scope. In this case the code in the tag logic:present will be executed.